# getRepository with javascript symfony

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I work with Symfony 2.8, and I have 3 selects list. the options of the 1st and the 2nd are called from the Repository in the controller like this :

**Contoller**

```
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$categories = $em->getRepository('CentralBundle:Categorie')->findAll();
$sousCategories = $em->getRepository('CentralBundle:SousCategorie')->findAll();

 return $this->render('product.html.twig',array('categories'=>$categories,
                                                                         'sousCategories' => $sousCategories));
```

**TWIG**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked category-menu">
 <select id="select-cat"  class="form-control" name="carlist">
   {% for cat in categories %}
     <option value="{{cat.id}}">{{cat.nom}}<option>
   {% endfor %}
  </select>  
 </ul>

 <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked category-menu">
 <select id="select-sc"  class="form-control" name="carlist">
   {% for sc in sousCategories %}
     <option value="{{sc.id}}">{{sc.nom}}<option>
   {% endfor %}
  </select>  
 </ul>
```

for the 3rd select list it should be called in function with the 1st and the 2nd select lists : it should be display th product wwith "categorie" and "sousCatogries" who are selected in the first step. So I think that is should be doing with javascript but the problem is how can I getRepository in javascript to get the list of product corresponding, or if there are an other solution to do that

thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in 2 ways

**AJAX**

First in ajax, just listen to select1 and select2 changes then call a new action that will query your database with select1 and select2 values then return the result in JSON format

```
$('.select1').change(function() {
    populateSelect3();
});
$('.select2').change(function() {
    populateSelect3();
});

function populateSelect3() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'myurl',
        type: 'post',
        data : {'select1': $('.select1').val(), 'select2': $('.select2').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            // populate your select3
        }
        ...
    );
}
```

**The SYMFONIC way**

Symfony Form component provide a way to dynamically update your form thanks to events, see here [Symfony Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

You will have to create a custom Form...

Comment: Thank u I will try to do that, and I will review

Comment: For the Symfony Form Events , event->getData() always NULL, and for the JavaScript Issue the problem is how to pass the query builder !